# Retrieve 3 sample values from table for each column

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to make query that will retrieve just random (or just unique) sample values from each column as a overview for user what format are values in the table.

table:

| project | customer | geography |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | c2 | Europe |
| p2 | c4 | US |
| p3 | c6 | Japan |
| p2 | c9 | US |
| p4 | c1 | Asia |
| ... | ... | ... |

expected result (random values):

| project | customer | geography |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p4 | c9 | Asia |
| p2 | c1 | US |
| p3 | c6 | Japan |

Retrieve top values is not correct as it usually returns same values or related values (like 3 project but with same geo).

```
select * from table limit 3
```

- table might have 100+ columns if geography is distinct the all
- columns are distinct

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select distinct * from table order by customers desc, geography asc limit 3;
```

Or you can try this one (This is little lengthy one):

```
select distinct * from table where project='p1' limit 1
union distinct 

select distinct * from table where project='p2' and customer not in (select distinct customer from table where project='p1') and geography not in (select distinct geography from table where project='p1') limit 1
union distinct 

select distinct * from table where project='p3' and customer not in (select distinct customer from table where project not in ('p1','p2')) and geography not in (select distinct geography from table where project not in ('p1','p2')) limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you but this would return almost same result as my code. Project would be unique, but not customer or geography.

Comment: If there are same multiple customers and locations for same project then it will not. In that case just check my updated query if that works with your data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you would like to see three unique values from each column and they should be independent of each other. Try this one

```
with project_t as (
  select row_number() over (order by project) rn, project
  from (select distinct project from tab limit 3) t
),
customer_t as (
  select row_number() over (order by customer) rn, customer
  from (select distinct customer from tab limit 3) t
),
geography_t as (
  select row_number() over (order by geography) rn, geography
  from (select distinct geography from tab limit 3) t
)
select p.project, c.customer, g.geography
from project_t p
join customer_t c on p.rn = c.rn
join geography_t g on c.rn = g.rn
```

I have tested just on [mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f07df22be108edb123cd61b0c93f3cf3), however, window functions and CTE should be available in Netezza as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not very SQL'ish because it dissociates the values in each column from each other.

You also have an issue if any column doesn't actually have three values.  I would recommend using `union all` and aggregation:

```
select max(project), max(customer), max(geography)
from ((select project, null as customer, null as geography,
              row_number() over (order by random) as seqnum
       from t
       group by project
      ) union all
      (select null, project, customer, null as geography,
              row_number() over (order by random) as seqnum
       from t
       group by customer
      ) union all
      (select null as project, null as customer, geography,
              row_number() over (order by random) as seqnum
       from t
       group by geography
      ) 
     ) pcg
where seqnum <= 3
group by seqnum;
```

This will return 3 rows whenever there are at least three distinct values in at least one of the columns.

If you want the most common values, just replace `random()` with `count(*) desc` in the `order by` clauses.

Comment: I agree it is not SQL'ish but I was thinking that maybe if only geography (highest level) is distinct then all the other columns should be distinct as well. So if I pull distinct value per geography and for other columns just random line for that geography...

Answer (score 0):

After you have run a ‘generate statistics’ on your table (which you SHOULD do weekly or so for performance reasons) you can find two values: the HIVAL and LOWAL
They can be be found in the catalog together with the number of distinct values in the column and the number of NULLs

So: if tree is a hard number, I cannot help, but if in my shop we run a ‘fast data profiling’ query against the catalog whenever necessary and continue from there whith more specific SQL, and simply focus on updating statistics....

I’ll share that SQL query if anybody Is interested ????